# unless in perl equivalent to ! in javascript?

Tags: javascript, perl, logical-operators

if I have an expression in perl:

`isOK` is a property of record. it is 1 or 0.

```
unless ( record.isOK )
```

My understanding is that is equivalent in javascript to:

```
if ( !record.isOK )
```

so `unless` corresponds in javascript to whatever the logical expression is with `!` before.

Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct. `unless(expr) == if (!expr)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl, `unless (EXPR)` is completely equivalent to `if ( !(EXPR) )`.

The `EXPR` is an expression which is evaluated in scalar context, imposed by `if` (and `unless`). I've added parenthesis in `!(EXPR)` as a reminder to watch for precedence as `!` binds tightly.

Note that you'll more often see `not` instead of `!` and that they [bind differently](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity), where `not` has very low precedence.